# Static library in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, static-libraries

I have created a static library and added it to my project, when i try to debug my application it goes to the .m file of the library. If this library is distributed to some one he will also be able to see code in that library which is blunder, how should i get rid of this.Are there any settings that are to be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't distribute the source file, they cannot see the source file. They may be able to see symbols within the library, such as function or method names, if you don't strip the binary after building it. There is a setting in the "Build Settings" of the project and target settings where you can turn stripping on or off. I believe that it's on for debug and off for release by default.

Comment: U mean to say that i should only distribute the .a file with .h files.Can u please what all should i change? I have added a image with default settings.

Comment: Yes, only distribute the .a and .h files. It looks to me like you have the right settings. "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" is set to "Yes" for release and "No" for debug. That should do what you want.